# Cannot query some objects on a schemna

Tags: db2

I have access to some schema in different database and as part of some migration work, I am comparing 2 schema.
I am using `Syscat` to compare the 2 schema. However in one of the schema, I get an error saying

> "user does not have select privilege on "

I would like to know , how can I see what and all access permissions have been set up in a particular schema (basically all users who have access and the type of access for a gievn schema). The database is db2. 
Please note that I am not using any tool like schema crawler etc. Instead I am writing a JDBC application which uses the `Syscat` to query the details like `select * from syscat.tables where tabSchema = <schemaName>`

Using a tool etc is a long process in terms to getting approval , justification etc (and I personally think that JDBC program should be good to start with the analysis).

Answer (score 0):

In DB2 privileges granted on a schema do not give you any privileges on objects belonging to that schema (unless you created those objects yourself). You have to be granted explicit object privileges or certain database level privileges, such as DATAACCESS.

The actual DB2 error message should contain the name of the object that generates the error. Try printing the String representation of the SQLException object.

Comment: Hello, Sorry for the confusion,the error which I talked about is coming in SQL Editor(I am using AquaData Studio). So I want to know , how to know for a given schema, which and all permissions are in place.

Comment: For a schema or for objects in that schema? For schema privileges query `SYSCAT.SCHEMAAUTH`; for each object type query the corresponding view, e.g. `SYSCAT.TABAUTH` for table privileges.

Answer (score 0):

A schema is a logical group of objects. These objects can be views, tables, indexes, sequences, functions, sotred procedures, etc. Each of these objects has a different set of privileges: table has select, insert, delete and others; stored procedure has the execution and others; etc. It means that every single object has different types of privileges, and you cannot get "all privilegesfor a given schema", you have to give the type of object.

For example, in order to get the privileges on tables for a given schema, you can execute

```
db2 "
select substr(GRANTEE,1,16),GRANTEETYPE,substr(tabschema || '.' || tabname,1,64),
CONTROLAUTH, ALTERAUTH, DELETEAUTH, INDEXAUTH, INSERTAUTH, REFAUTH, SELECTAUTH, UPDATEAUTH 
from syscat.TABAUTH 
where tabschema like 'MYSCHEMA%'"
```

Each kind of object that a table in syscat schema that contains the privileges for that kind of object. You just have to query the table.

In a similar way, you can create the appropiated sentences in order to grant or revoke privileges on an object

```
select 'grant select on ' || trim(tabschema) || '.' || trim(tabname) ' to user johndoe'
from syscat.tables
where tabschema like 'MYSCHE%'
```

Finally, there are not only privileges (grants) on db2, there are also database level authorities, and some of them have privileges on all objects.

Comment: this is what I meant

On logging to schema (say SCHEMA) .. I execute the following query

select count(1) from syscat.tabauth
and get the below error. So would like to know.. who and all users have access to query

tabauth

.

>[Error] Script lines: 1-2 --------------------------
 DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, SQLERRMC=xxxxx;SELECT;SYSCAT.TABAUTH, DRIVER=3.50.152
 Message: "xxxxx" does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform operation "SELECT" on object "SYSCAT.TABAUTH".. SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, DRIVER=3.50.152

Comment: That is normal. The user you are using to execute does not have privileges on these catalog tables (tabauth ou schemaauth). It seems that you are using a restricted database, it means, it does not have privileges on public. There is nothing you can do to retrieve the privileges with your current user.